# Javascript getDate pulling seemingly random dates

Tags: javascript, date

I am a newbie to javascript, and what I am trying to do is this: The webpage prompts you with "how many nights will you be staying?" you put in a number and it is supposed to look something like this "Total cost for checking in [today date] and checking our [nights staying] cost $"

I can't get the date to display the [nights stayed] if just gives random dates not x days from today. here is an example of what is displayed if i enter 5 in the prompt
"Total cost for checking in Thu Sep 24 2020 and checking out Wed Jan 01 0245 is $500" not even a real year, nor is it 5 days from today.

```
var totalnights = prompt('How many nights will you be staying?');

var today;
var costMsg;
var nights;

function TotalCost(today) {
   
nights = new Date(new Date().getDate()+(totalnights));
    nights = (nights.toDateString());
    

today = new Date()
    today = (today.toDateString());


var Msg = 'Total cost for checking in ' + today + ' and checking out ' + nights + ' is ' + '$' + hotel.roomRate * totalnights ;
return Msg;
}
```

Comment: `new Date(new Date().getDate()+(totalnights));` you're adding `totalNights` to the date of month ... so you're creating a date from a number less than 50 ... so your date is 1 january 1970 - that's not anywhere near the code I suggested in your previous question - try https://pastebin.com/dtFGQ4fp

Answer (score 0):

The place you are going wrong is the date calculation. new Date().getDate() just gives back the current and the expected input parameter for the Date are given in the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You can fix the above code by

```
let night = new Date()
night.setDate(night.getDate() + totalnights)
```

Comment: thanks man, will update the answer